# Omit Null in console while using ggsave within a function

Tags: r

I am using ggsave within functions to automatically save plotts while running the code. I do it with variable path and graphic settings. So far so good.
What it does is, it always states a "NULL" in the console with each plott saved.
I am wondering if there is a way to either omit the "NULL" or better to return either the path where the file is saved or the filename.

```
print(ggsave(paste(Graphics_path, "Subfolder Name", "Filename.pdf", sep="\\"), width=gr_width, height=gr_height, dpi=gr_dpi))
```

Also when I define path and filename separately it returns a "NULL".

```
print(ggsave(filename="Filename.pdf", path=paste(Graphics_path, "Subfolder Name", sep="\\"), width=gr_width, height=gr_height, dpi=gr_dpi))
```

Comment: Why do you have `print()` in your code? I think you should simply remove that.

Comment: I thought I'd have to add a print() since I am using it within a function, the same way I call to ggplot with the print(). But thanks, without it does work as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Andrie is correct, when you remove `print()` the NULL will disappear. However, you will get a message that says something like *Saving # x # in image*  for each plot you save.

To remove that message use `suppressMessages(ggsave(...))`

Comment: I manually added width and height settings and it didn't show any messages anymore after removing the print statement. Thanks